# Global function call in Swift? Howto?

Tags: function, swift, sprite-kit, global, skscene

I have a Swift noobie question on class method calls. I'm building a simple learning app for my kids using Sprite Kit. I have a global variable scoreCount defined in GameScene, where I pretty much do all my game logic such as detect correct answer and increment scoreCount. I also have GameOverScene. On both I show the Score -label. I'm keeping count of scores with the scoreCount-parameter (in GameScene). However as I'm quite new to Swift and Sprite Kit, I'm wondering how should I update the score label in GameViewController? So basically I would like to call GameViewController.updateLabels() from GameScene.

I know this isn't the ideal way but please share your solution concept on this. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well. 
In your GameViewController you have to transform your func in class func like this

```
class func yourFunc {
 //your code
}
```

To call it from your GameScene just this code :

```
GameViewController.yourFunc()
```

Don't forget you are creating a **global** function so all variables in it have to be global too.

For you label (global):

```
var label:UILabel = UILabel()
```

in Your GameViewController:

```
class GameViewController : UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    label.text = "bonjour" // to set the text
    label.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100) / set the position AND size CGRectMake (x, y, width, heigth)

    label.textColor = UIColor.redColor() // set your color
    label.center = CGPointMake(self.view.frame.width/2, self.view.frame.height/2) // set the position from x=0 and y=0
    self.view.addSubview(label) // add the label to your screen
```

I hope it will help you.

Comment: This does help me but I'm still stuck with not being able to introduce my labels as global variables. If I move the label outside of the class: @IBOutlet weak var livesCounter: UILabel! I get: "Only instance properties can be declared 'IBOutlet'"

Comment: Do you use the storyboard?

Comment: Yes, created the labels on storyboard and dragged them into code using assistant editor.

Comment: Okay. You can directly code them without the storyboard. Like this you will be able to set them as global. Delete them from the storyboard and in your GameViewController delete `@IBOutlet weak`. Declare out of the class your variable `var livesCounter:UILabel!`

Comment: I can help you to set the label properties if you need

Comment: Thanks! I'll appreciate all the help. I feel like first year university student all over again. I did as you instructed but after that the app crashed for the labels having nil value. I started to work with override init() to initialize the labels and suddently found my self wondering what "required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)" does.

Comment: Don't worry I'm a noob too... I develop iOS application for 2 months ! I will try to help you as I can. See my edit answer