# How to correctly initialize global variable for a game in swift

Tags: swift, global-variables

I have a trivia game/app that has 4 sections. I am trying to keep score across the 4 sections, while also updating the overall score. I followed this question [The best way to implement lives and score count in Sprite Kit (static, IoC, other?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26448678/the-best-way-to-implement-lives-and-score-count-in-sprite-kit-static-ioc-othe) and followed the link to the tutorial written in OBJ C. In an attempt to convert the tutorial code from Obj C to Swift - I came up with this -

```
class Scoring: NSObject {
    var tfscore: Int = 0
    var mcscore: Int = 0
    var mapsscore: Int = 0
    var photoscore: Int = 0
    var overallscore: Int = 0

    class func sharedGameData() -> Self {
        return sharedGameData()
    }
}
```

I can then call the scoring items such as this -

```
@IBAction func answerButtonHandler(sender: UIButton) {
    if sender.titleLabel!.text == correctAnswer {
        ayuh()
        truefalsescore += 1
        Scoring.sharedGameData().tfscore = truefalsescore
        Scoring.sharedGameData().overallscore = truefalsescore
    }
}
```

however, when i build and run, I get an error/crash on the  ***return sharedGameData()*** line as soon as the score changes.

Am I initializing it correctly? 
Is this the best way to grab scores from various sections and be able to add them, access them?
Thanks,
Eric

Answer (score 2):

You will fall into infinite recursion because you call `sharedGameData()` in itself.

Please, try the following:

```
class Scoring {

    static let sharedGameData = Scoring()

    var tfscore: Int = 0
    var mcscore: Int = 0
    var mapsscore: Int = 0
    var photoscore: Int = 0
    var overallscore: Int = 0

    init () {

    }
}
```

Now, you can `Scoring.sharedGameData.tfscore += 1` or whatever anywhere in your code.

Comment: Thanks! Please, accept this as an answer if my reply was helpful  ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `Constants.swift` file, where you put all your shared variables:

```
import Foundation

var tfscore: Int = 0
var mcscore: Int = 0
var mapsscore: Int = 0
var photoscore: Int = 0
var overallscore: Int = 0
```

Then, you can access those wherever you want in your code.

Hope it helps